"Normalize" duration time data and plot in Matlab
I have the following data sets that have in the x-axis time in "HH:mm:ss".
Each data set has different numbers of "times" but they are all within a 2hr duration.
I want to plot this data in terms of duration in minutes on the x-axes on the same plot.
set0_time=["085440","091530","092000","093020","100000","100020","101325"];
set0_ydata=[30 50 60 72 82 85 88];
H_set0 = str2double(extractBefore(set0_time(:),3));
M_set0 = str2double(extractBetween(set0_time(:),3,4));
S_set0 = str2double(extractAfter(set0_time(:),4));
D_set0 = duration(H_set0,M_set0,S_set0);
t_minutes_set0 = minutes(D_set0);

set1_time = ["121101","121105","130001","133025","140000"];
set1_ydata=[40 50 60 70 89];
H_set1 = str2double(extractBefore(set1_time(:),3));
M_set1 = str2double(extractBetween(set1_time(:),3,4));
S_set1 = str2double(extractAfter(set1_time(:),4));
D_set1 = duration(H_set1,M_set1,S_set1);
t_minutes_set1 = minutes(D_set1);
tdiff_minutes_set1 = t_minutes_set1 - t_minutes_set0(1:5); %There is an issue selecting the first five of set0 as the shift is not accurate
tdiff_shift_set1 = t_minutes_set1-tdiff_minutes_set1;

set2_time = ["103235","110010","120000","130130"];
set2_ydata=[37.8 70 85.7 93.6];
H_set2 = str2double(extractBefore(set2_time(:),3));
M_set2 = str2double(extractBetween(set2_time(:),3,4));
S_set2 = str2double(extractAfter(set2_time(:),4));
D_set2 = duration(H_set2,M_set2,S_set2);
t_minutes_set2 = minutes(D_set2);
tdiff_minutes_set2 = t_minutes_set2 - t_minutes_set0(1:4); %There is an issue selecting the first four of set0 as the shift is not accurate
tdiff_shift_set2 = t_minutes_set2-tdiff_minutes_set2;

figure
scatter(t_minutes_set0,set0_ydata,'Marker','o', 'DisplayName','set0') %updated this line
hold on;
scatter(tdiff_shift_set1,set1_ydata,'Marker','*', 'DisplayName','set1')
scatter(tdiff_shift_set2,set2_ydata,'Marker','+', 'DisplayName','set2')
hold off
xlabel('Duration');
ylabel('Data');
legend

I'm not sure how to "normalize" the data set "times" so that the "data" is plotted in the same duration, even though the length of the data sets are different.
Any insights are appreciated.

Cast all time points to seconds after onset?

What does this mean: so that the "data" is plotted in the same duration? Could you mock up what your expected output looks like in Paint (or similar) to clarify how you expect the series to look? Do you expect the x-axis to be the % of time between the first and last time in each series?

You are working with time stamps. Such data has been collected in string format. Get it all to minutes right at the beginning and then use histogram to sort data along histogram bins. Doing a histogram with characters is not going to follow the same order as when working directly with minutes only, or better, work it all to seconds and then get minutes before presenting results
